# I have been using TeamViewer with my phone, but can't connect my new tablet

Tags: wireless-networking

I have a Samsung Galaxy S3 which has no problem connecting but when I try with my 10" Audiosonic tablet it appears to start then says "The session with 873645236549 is finished". Then another screen comes up saying "Please wait while connecting" which just stays there and nothing seems to happen.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an Android, WinMobile or iOS operating system on the mobile device, I suggest [Splashtop](http://www.splashtop.com/personal) as an alternative for GUI-based remote control.  I have the business edition, but the personal edition you can use 1 seat (seat = the user who connects to the remote desktop at anytime; the same user ) connecting to one remote computer.

Splashtop does have a desktop viewer as well, but the viewer seems to work better in the mobile devices.  I use [AmmyyAdmin](http://www.ammyy.com/en/) or regular Microsoft's Remote Desktop Connection for accessing any desktop.

In order to fully take advantage of Splashtop, Ammyy Admin, etc for a remote desktop that does not have a monitor attached, you need to create a windows user session (user1) within a session (user2) then you connect to user2, which will then have user1's RDP session always open.  So it appears that user1's virtual monitor is open.  You can watch a video on how to do it on  [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SoybUfW0VdY)

Then you use Ammyy or Splashtop to connect to user1's desktop.